# Hiding UITabBarController in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I used code below to hide tab bar in iOS6:

```
int ht = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    for (UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, ht, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        }
        else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, ht)];
        }
    }
```

Now I tried to use it in iOS7, although it hides the tab, but still the bottom of screen is not clickable.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexVogel Yes, but using simple ViewController and omitting iOS built in bar at all! :)